Why entra external id doesn't return the email calim?
I Follow the Step to chosse email claim.
#https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/optional-claims#
Why cliams doesn't have email ?
After login in local website , all claims i get are here:
aio ATQAy/xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
login_hint  O.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
name    unknown
oid ee9114bf-74e6-4e1f-b56e-xxxxxxxx
rh  0.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-gAFM.
sid xxxxx-xxxx-40e1-ac2c-xxxxxx
sub xxxxxxxxx-aLVyAfHZaQb1rlx6J6D9lJkCzdCGE4
tid xxxxxxxxxx-d668-495b-a1ed-xxxxxxxx
uti xxxxxxxxxxxx
utid    xxxxxxx-d668-495b-a1ed-xxxxxxxxxxxx
uid xxxxxxxxxx-74e6-4e1f-b56e-edda2963afa3

Things I Do:
I has been choosen email claim in Token configuration.
Token configuration
I Provide all the permisson and agree as administor:
Microsoft Graph (5)
email
offline_access
openid
profile
API permissions

Is there a chance you can paste your app manifest content? Can be without the app ids and other PII content.
